# Multiple aggregate functions on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Trying to run the below line

```
df = df.groupby(['Name', 'ID']).agg(Average_Revenue=('Amount', np.mean), Sum_Revenue=('Amount', np.sum))
```

but I recieve the error:

> TypeError: func is expected but received tuple in **kwargs.

According to all the documentation I have looked at not sure why this is giving an error, can anyone help please

Comment: what's your `pd.__version__`? named aggregation requires at least v0.25.0

Comment: I just checked and i have pandas 1.5.0

Comment: you should post a small sample dataframe that can reproduce the error

Comment: sorry guys I just found my error, I was trying to use this line of code on a dataframe that was already grouped.  I Apologize for wasting everyones time

Answer (score 1):

can you post some data, versions, etc?
this seems to work for me on Python 3.7.6, pandas 1.2.1, numpy 1.20.0:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['joe', 111, 25.0],
    ['joe', 111, 30.0]
], columns=['Name', 'ID', 'Amount'])
df.groupby(['Name', 'ID']).agg(Average_Revenue=('Amount', np.mean), Sum_Revenue=('Amount', np.sum))

        Average_Revenue Sum_Revenue
Name    ID      
joe 111 27.5    55.0
```

Comment: Same here (it works): Python 3.9.13, pandas 1.4.2, numpy 1.23.2